# Convert d3 svg coordinates to canvas coordinates or try to match the same position for both

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, canvas, coordinates

I have some d3 svg elements in which I pass as attribute a list of coordinates x,y and I plot them on a svg map. Like the example below:

```
var svg = iniMarker().append("g")
   .attr("data-lineData", JSON.stringify(lineData))
//Function to draw line
        var lineFunction = d3.svg.line()
            .x(function (d) { return d.x; })
            .y(function (d) { return d.y; });
```

The resulting path structure is like this:

```
<path d="M1100,850L1180,800" class="pPath" stroke-dasharray="94.33981323242188 94.33981323242188" stroke-dashoffset="0"></path>
<path d="M1180,800L1280,800" class="pPath" stroke-dasharray="100 100" stroke-dashoffset="0"></path>
<path d="M1280,800L1380,800" class="pPath" stroke-dasharray="100 100" stroke-dashoffset="0"></path>
```

On the top of this line path there is also a circle which takes as input the line data coordinates values:

```
var circle = svg.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 10)
                .attr("fill", "#fff")
                .attr("class", "marker")
                .attr("transform", function () {
                    return "translate(" + lineData[0].x + "," + lineData[0].y + ")";
                });
```

The data where I take the coordinates information are store in this format:

```
var DataSet = [{
            "id": "",
            "isActive": true,
            "personId": "p1",
            "name": "test",
            "lineData": [
                { "timestamp": "2018/09/15 10:00:05 AM", "x": 1100, "y": 950 }]
```

Now I need to represent each of these points taken from this coordinates list **on a canvas map exactly superimposed on the svg map**. **And in that case the problem is that the svg coordinates of the list don't match the same position of the canvas coordinates.**

In fact if I try to generate some canvas coordinate points by using the function below:

```
document.getElementById("canv").onclick = function (e) {
            var localX = e.clientX - e.target.offsetLeft;
            var localY = e.clientY - e.target.offsetTop;
}
```

Then the coordinates at the `onclick` event are pretty much different from the svg coordinates that I have from DataSet obj as position.

Actually in order to match them, I have just tried to pass the DataSet obj on a function in order to get the svg coordinates and plot them on the canvas map, like this:

```
DataSet.map(function (m) { if(m.isActive) return m.lineData; else return []; }).forEach(f => data = data.concat(f));

            data.forEach(e => {
                //here I call another function for plot the svg coordinates as points on the canvas map 
});
```

But it's obvious that I need to convert them first in order to match correctly.

Following the suggestion of @enxaneta I need to create a canvas from these data objects. But the problem is that the coordinates that I already have are for svg, not for canvas format.

I need to find a way to convert the list of svg coordinates that I have in order to match or be more similar as possibile to the canvas coordinates system.

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried d3.mouse for getting the coordinates?

Comment: @Raju if you refer to svg coordinates I already have them.. and if you refer to get the canvas coordinates, the problem is that they are actually correct by using targe.offset function.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] rather than just disconnected fragments of code and data.

Comment: @RobertLongson thank for this advice. Let me try to recreate a minimal working example in order to show exactly the problem about coordinates matching between svg and canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear but assuming that you have an svg path, you can transform it to a canvas path using the [Path2D](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D) object: In the next example the SVG paths are red, the canvas paths are left black.

```js
var svgPathApple = Apple.getAttribute("d");
var svgPathLeaf = Leaf.getAttribute("d");

var c = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var cw = c.width = 500;
var ch = c.height = 500;

var apple = new Path2D(svgPathApple);
var leaf = new Path2D(svgPathLeaf);

ctx.stroke(apple);
ctx.stroke(leaf);
```

```css
canvas,svg{border:1px solid #d9d9d9; width:45vw;}
path{fill: none; stroke:red;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 500 500">

 <path id="Apple" d="M376.349,171.58
  c0,0-37.276,22.484-36.094,60.946s31.438,61.577,42.012,63.313c4.127,0.678-24.314,57.988-42.039,72.189
  s-36.067,17.159-64.47,5.917c-28.403-11.242-48.521,0.724-65.089,6.871s-36.687-0.361-63.905-39.415
  s-57.396-129.585-15.976-173.964s87.574-26.627,100-20.71s34.32,5.325,59.172-5.917S363.922,153.237,376.349,171.58z"/>

 <path id="Leaf" d="M311.852,68.621c0,0,2.367,14.793-3.55,27.219
  s-28.189,55.061-60.473,47.337c-0.809-0.193-5.529-14.482,1.398-29.002C259.004,93.682,284.49,70.699,311.852,68.621z"/>

</svg>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

UPDATE:

SVG stands for Scalable Vector Graphics. Although your svg size is the same as your  canvas size, in facr your svg is four time as big. In order to know the real size you have to look at the value of the `viewBox` attribute: "52 0 2104 1200". Translated to plain english the width of your svg is 2104, and the height is 1200. And this is not all. Your svg coordinates start at x=52 and y = 0. Given a point p={x:100,y:100} on the SVG, your canvas coordinates are: `x = (100 - 52)/2` and `y = 100/2`;

Next comes a simple example where I'm drawing a circle on canvas and on the svg element:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canv");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let x = (100 - 52)/2, 
    y = 100/2,
    r = 10/2;


ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x,y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.fill();
```

```css
canvas,svg{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="svgMap" width="1052px" height="600px" viewBox="52 0 2104 1200">
  <circle  id="testCircle" cx="100" cy ="100" r="10" />
</svg>


<canvas width="1052" height="600" id="canv"></canvas>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @enxaneta so if I have understand well the coordinates of the svg path change when I convert the svg element path to canvas with Path2D? But let's say that I pass directly only the coordinates object parameter on a function, like {timestamp: "2018/09/15 10:00:05 AM", x: 1100, y: 950}... in this case is there now way to change to changes the svg coordinates (x and y) in order to match with the canvas coordinates mapping system?

Comment: @UgoL the coordinates do not change. You can draw the same path but this time on the canvas instead of svg. I don't understand exactly what type of data you have, I suppose it's some sort of objects array, each object with a timestamp, and an x and y coordinates. Please edit your question by adding a short example of data array + the size of the canvas you need to draw on. I'll try to help.

Comment: Thanks @enxaneta give me some time for update the question in the right way. I'll try to add more details, especially the data that I need to manipulate.

Comment: I have updated the question..I don't know if now is more clear or not. let me know you you got my point. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yet an other question: what is the size of your canvas and the value of the viewBox of your svg?

Comment: About canvas <canvas width="1052" height="600" id="canv" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 1052px; position: relative; opacity: 0.5; left: 0px; top: -604px; display: none;"></canvas>

Comment: About svg <svg version="1.1" id="svgMap" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
            width="1052px" height="600px" viewBox="52 0 2104 1200">

Comment: Thank you very much @enxaneta.. I'm just reading right now. Gove me some minutes for understand it.

Comment: I have tried to change like that-> addData(((e.x - 52) / 2), (e.y / 2) , (20/2)); in order to make the svg points that I pass to canvas map matching with the canvas coordinates format, but it seems not working as expected. Cause for just the first one ojb the points plotted are corrects. If I add another obj with different svg coordinates then it seems showing the points not in the correct place as well (it shows them in the opposite side, I recognized the points path is correct but is the position that is still wrong).

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. Is your other object a different svg element?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180790/discussion-between-ugol-and-enxaneta).